# Android UIWebView overflow-y: auto with :hover

Tags: android

I have a very odd problem that doesn't happen in Chrome for Android, but it does happen when using a web view in an application in less than Android 4.4

The bug is:

When tapping in a 147px area near the sidebar, it causes the sidebar to open. This is because there is `:hover` on `#sidebar`. It is unexpected because the width is only 47px. It appears to be caused by `overflow-y:auto`. Removing this fixes the problem (But breaks the application as I need the scrolling)

I am using Android 4.3. It does NOT happen in 4.4 because the web view rendering engine is different.

The following behavior happens. I have a #sidebar that is collapsed at 47px

I have the following css.

```
#sidebar:hover
{
  width:175px;  
}

#sidebar
{
   width:47px;  
   overflow-y:auto !important;
}
```

Here is a visual of the problem:

[image: Android Bug]

I am looking for a way to fix this and still retain functionality of overflow: auto

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround as this seems like a browser bug. I ended up doing min-height: 1000px on #sidebar instead of doing the overflow, this is not perfect but it works